# React component not rendering with updated state values (react-redux toolkit)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm using react-redux for a tickets app project and I have a dashboard page that renders all of the submitted tickets. On this dashboard, there is a button to open a modal form that creates a new ticket when the form is submitted.

The issue that I am running into it is that after I submit the form, the ticket item renders on the page, but none of the values from the form are populating the fields unless I refresh the page. I checked to see if the values were updated via react dev tools and redux dev tools *before* the refresh and the values are there but they just don't populate the item until I refresh. I also tried calling getTicket after the createTicket dispatch within the onSubmit handler for the modal form but this didn't work.

The only thing I found that worked was to use useNavigate(0) to reload the page but that defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do.

Below is the code for each page:

**Dashboard Page**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getTicket, reset } from "../features/tickets/ticketsSlice";
import TicketsItem from "../components/TicketsItem";
import Spinner from "../components/Spinner";
import SubmitTicketModal from "../components/SubmitTicketModal";

function Dashboard() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  // Initialize navigate and dispatch
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Get user data from state
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { tickets, isLoading, isError, message } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.tickets
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) {
      console.log(message);
    }

    if (!user) {
      navigate("/login");
    }

    dispatch(getTicket());

    return () => {
      dispatch(reset);
    };
  }, [user, navigate, isError, message, dispatch]);

  // Handle loading state    
  if (isLoading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <section className='dashboard'>
        <h1 className='dashboard-heading'>Welcome, {user && user.name}!</h1>

        <div className='dashboard-content'>
          <div className='dashboard-btn-container'>
            <button className='btn-primary' onClick={openModal}>
              New Ticket
            </button>
          </div>

          {/* Handle mapping of ticket data to TicketItem component */}
           <section>
            {tickets.length > 0 ? (
              tickets.map((ticket, index) => (
                <TicketsItem ticket={ticket} key={index} />
              ))
            ) : (
              <h3>No open tickets.</h3>
            )}
          </section>
        </div>
      </section>
      {/* Open modal based on state value */}
      {isOpen && <SubmitTicketModal closeModal={setIsOpen} />}
    </>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

**Modal Component**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { createTicket } from "../features/tickets/ticketsSlice";

function SubmitTicketModal({ closeModal }) {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
  });

  // Destructure from formData
  const { title, description } = formData;

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const ticketData = {
      title,
      description,
    };

    dispatch(createTicket(ticketData));
    setFormData("");
    closeModal(false);
  };

  // Close modal window function
  const closeModalWindow = () => {
    closeModal(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className='modal-container'>
        <div className='modal-box'>
          <button className='close-modal-btn' onClick={closeModalWindow}>
            X
          </button>
          <h1>Submit New Ticket</h1>

          <div className='form-group'>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
              <label htmlFor='title'>Subject:</label>
              <input type='text' id='title' name='title' onChange={onChange} />
              <label htmlFor='description'>Describe your issue:</label>
              <textarea
                name='description'
                id='description'
                resize='none'
                onChange={onChange}></textarea>

              <button className='btn-primary' type='submit'>
                Submit New Ticket
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default SubmitTicketModal;
```

**Ticket Item Component**

```
function TicketsItem({ ticket }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className='ticket-item'>
        <div className='ticket-heading'>
          <div className='ticket-heading-title-container'>
            <h3 className='ticket-title'>{ticket.title}</h3>
            <p className='ticket-id'>(id: {ticket._id})</p>
          </div>
          <div className='ticket-status'>
            <p>Solved</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='ticket-date'>Submitted on: Mon, September 20, 2022</div>

        <div className='ticket-body'>{ticket.description}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default TicketsItem;
```

**Tickets Slice**

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import ticketsService from "./ticketsService";

const initialState = {
  tickets: [],
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: "",
};

// Create ticket
export const createTicket = createAsyncThunk(
  "tickets/create",
  async (ticketData, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await ticketsService.createTicket(ticketData, token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();

      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

// Get tickets
export const getTicket = createAsyncThunk(
  "tickets/getAll",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await ticketsService.getTickets(token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();

      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

export const ticketsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ticket",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState,
  },

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(createTicket.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(createTicket.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.tickets.push(action.payload);
      })
      .addCase(createTicket.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getTicket.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getTicket.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.tickets = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getTicket.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const { reset } = ticketsSlice.actions;
export default ticketsSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-sound-uwpi2o?file=/src/TicketsSlice.js. Maybe `ticketsService.createTicket` returns something incorrect.

Comment: @user4980215 ticketsService.createTicket is using axios to make a post request to the associated API endpoint with the ticketData. The bearer token is being passed in the headers and returning the response.data Here is a codepen with the function code (https://codepen.io/orreryofcode/pen/oNqOOpb)

Comment: Just `console.log(response.data)` to see whats there. It should be a new ticket `{ _id, title, description }`.

Comment: @user4980215 I figured it out! console.log(response.data) was logging a nested object with the ticket data I wanted nested one level deep. I changed it from response.data to response.data.ticket and now it's rendering correctly. 

Thanks for your help!